# How would I provide a dynamic token to a module?

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

I'm trying to wrap my head around Dagger2. I'm having trouble understanding how would I provide a parameter for a dependency that is shared around the whole app. Here's what I came up with (these are just dummy classes that I am using so I can understand the concepts):

```
class Token(val token: String)

class File @Inject constructor(@param:Named("token") val token: Token)

@Component(modules = arrayOf(SessionModule::class))
interface SessionManager {
    fun file(): File
}

@Module
class SessionModule {
    @Provides @Singleton fun provideToken(token: String) = Token(token)
}
```

Here's the thing:

I want `provideToken` to be a singleton, so that the same Token is always provided for people requesting the session. But I also want to be able to update the token, if needed. How would I do that? I thought about creating a static variable that holds the token inside the `SessionModule` class, but I think this can lead to spaghetti code real quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, you should not do that, don't inject dynamic stuff. Something like `String`, `List<String>` are not supposed to be injected by dagger. Dagger is used for injecting **static and cooperative** stuff.

You can save your token in memory or `SharePreference` whatever you like but through dagger.

Comment: That makes sense, I guess.